# Split one array to multiple array by key and value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have one array like below:

```
$ar = ['a'=>'apple', 'b'=>'banana', 'c'=>'pear'];
```

and i want to split to multiple array by key and value
my expected result

```
$new_ar=[['phrase'=>'a','fruit'=>'apple'],['phrase'=>'b','fruit'=>'banana'],['phrase'=>'c','fruit'=>'pear']];
```

Any solution for these thank you.

Comment: You would normally be expected to make some effort yourself before coming to SO for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make an array of keys, you can use `array_combine` inside `array_map` to generate your new array by combining the keys array with the key and value of each entry in `$ar`:

```
$keys = array('phrase', 'fruit');
$ar = ['a'=>'apple', 'b'=>'banana', 'c'=>'pear'];

$new_ar = array_map(function ($v, $k) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, array($k, $v));
}, $ar, array_keys($ar));

print_r($new_ar);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [phrase] => a
            [fruit] => apple
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [phrase] => b
            [fruit] => banana
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [phrase] => c
            [fruit] => pear
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6KlUA)

Answer (score 1):

In simple way. you can iterate `array` using `foreach` as follow

```
$new = [];
foreach($ar as $k => $v){
 $new[] = ['phrase' => $k, 'fruit' => $v];
}
print_r($new);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/8fpEK